# Making a row into a column

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, matrix

I am trying to make a row into a column. That is, I have `row = [2, 4, 8]`, and I need `[[2], [4], [8]]`.
So I made this code:

```
row = [2, 4, 8]
column = [[]] * 3
for y in range(3):
    column[y].append(row[y])
```

`column` has to be `[[2], [], []]` after the first loop. But it was `[[2], [2], [2]]`. Does anyone know what's the matter?

Comment: See [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: @khelwood Oh, that solved! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
raw = [2, 4, 8]
column =[]

for case in raw:
    column.append([case])
```

Concerning your question it should be because a list containing a value and the memory of the next iteration.

```
a = [1]
b = a
b[0] = 2
print(a)  # return [2]
```

Comment: Actually, in my real code, the for-loop is inside another loop, and the column is defined outside the loop. I need ````board = [[2, a1, b1], [4, a2, b2], [8, a3, b3]]````.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
column = [[i] for i in row]
```

as per the following transcript:

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> row = [2, 4, 8]
>>> column = [[i] for i in row]
>>> print(column)
[[2], [4], [8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#see if this soves your issue
row = [2, 4, 8]
col=[]
for i in row:
    col.append([i])
```